# Is there an equivalent argument to index_col in geopandas.read_file() function?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am looking for the equivalent argument to `pandas.read_csv(index_col='column')` in the `geopandas.read_file()` function. My goal is to read a shapefile and specify the index column. However, the following does not set any index column and returns the same `GeoDataframe` as calling the function without the argument:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('test.shp', index_col='column')
```

The [documentation](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file) of the `read_file` function does not list `index_col` as an argument and states that one can specify keyword arguments that are going to be passed to the `fiona.open` function (but not to any `pandas.read_*` function).

A workaround is to use the `set_index()` method after reading the file:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('test.shp')
gdf = gdf.set_index('column')

# or

gdf = gpd.read_file('test.shp').set_index('column')
```

However, it feels like specifying the index should be possible directly from the `read_file` function.

Comment: It is not. Your workaround with `set_index()` is the best option so far.

Comment: Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GeoPandas does not have such an option (as of 0.7.0 and likely 0.8.0), so the workaround with `.set_index` is the best option. If it did have the option, it would likely just do the same under the hood, so there will be no difference anyway.